# Printing the output to the SPSS Output window

Tags: python, spss

Hello I am trying to convert an Python script so that it is a standalone python script, but this does not work as expected.
The output is posted to the Python window and not the the normal SPSS output window - how can I fix this?

```
import spss
import SpssClient
import spssaux
from collections import defaultdict
import time
try:
    SpssClient.StartClient()
    SpssDataDoc=SpssClient.GetActiveDataDoc()

    print SpssDataDoc.GetDatasetName()
    print spssaux.GetActiveDatasetName()

    spssaux.spssaux.openDataFile("c:\bla.sav", filetype='sav')

    spss.spss.SetOutput("off")

    filterStr = """USE ALL.
    COMPUTE filter_$=({0}and category = {1}).
    FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0).
    FILTER BY filter_$.
    EXECUTE."""

    regressionStr ="""
    REGRESSION
      /DESCRIPTIVES MEAN STDDEV N
      /MISSING LISTWISE
      /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA COLLIN TOL
      /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
      /NOORIGIN 
      /DEPENDENT TotalLoyaltyScore
      /METHOD=ENTER var {0}
      /RESIDUALS DURBIN."""


      #initializing Lists
    CategoryDict = {1 : "Washing", 2: "dishwasher", 3: "Oven", 4:"Fridge", 5:"Vacuum"}
    CategoryVarDict = {1 : " recQ21r8 recQ21r9 recQ21r10 recQ21r11 recQ21r12 recQ21r13"}
    CategoryVarDict[2] = " recQ21r14 recQ21r15 recQ21r16 recQ21r17 recQ21r18 recQ21r19"
    CategoryVarDict[3] = " recQ21r20 recQ21r21 recQ21r22 recQ21r23 recQ21r24"
    CategoryVarDict[4] =" recQ21r25 recQ21r26 recQ21r27 recQ21r28 recQ21r29"
    CategoryVarDict[5] = " recQ21r30 recQ21r31 recQ21r32 recQ21r33 recQ21r34"

    VarDict = spssaux.spssaux.VariableDict()
    #vars = spssaux.spssaux.VariableDict().variables
    #for var in vars:
    #   print var

    ContinentVar = VarDict["Continent"]
    GenderVar = VarDict["Q25"]
    SchoolVar = VarDict["Q28"]
    AgeVar = VarDict["AgeEasy"]

    ContinentVL = spssaux.spssaux.GetValueLabels(ContinentVar)
    GenderVL = spssaux.spssaux.GetValueLabels(GenderVar)
    SchoolVL = spssaux.spssaux.GetValueLabels(SchoolVar)
    AgeVL = spssaux.spssaux.GetValueLabels(AgeVar)

    ToProcess = [ContinentVar, GenderVar, SchoolVar, AgeVar]
    SpssOutputDoc = SpssClient.GetDesignatedOutputDoc()

    for Category in CategoryDict:
        for Item in ToProcess:
            ValueLabel = spssaux.spssaux.GetValueLabels(Item)
            for Labels in ValueLabel:
                if not ValueLabel[Labels] == "no Answer":
                    SpssClient.LogToViewer("Category: " + CategoryDict[Category] + " Item: " + ValueLabel[Labels] +"\n")

                    # SpssOutputItem=SpssOutputDoc.CreateHeaderItem ("Category: " + CategoryDict[Category] + " Item: " + ValueLabel[Labels])
                    # itemlist = SpssOutputDoc.GetOutputItems()
                    # itemListLength = itemlist.Size()
                    # root = itemlist.GetItemAt(0).GetSpecificType()
                    # root.InsertChildItem(SpssOutputItem,root.GetChildCount())

                    spss.spss.Submit("title " + "" + "Category: " + CategoryDict[Category] + " Item: " + ValueLabel[Labels] + "" + "")
                    #Filtering
                    FirstPart = str(Item) + " =" + Labels + " "
                    realFilter = filterStr.format(FirstPart, Category)

                    #SpssClient.LogToViewer(realFilter)
                    spss.spss.Submit(realFilter.replace('\t',''))

                    #Regression
                    realRegression = regressionStr.format(CategoryVarDict[Category])
                    spss.spss.Submit(realRegression.replace('\t',''))

    OutputItems = SpssOutputDoc.GetOutputItems()
    for index in range(OutputItems.Size()):
        OutputItem = OutputItems.GetItemAt(index)
        if OutputItem.GetType() == SpssClient.OutputItemType.HEAD and OutputItem.GetDescription() == "Regression":
            TitleElem = OutputItems.GetItemAt(index-1)
            Spec = TitleElem.GetSpecificType()
            TitleText = Spec.GetTextContents()
            print(TitleText)


            OutputItem.SetDescription(TitleText)

            SItem = OutputItem.GetSpecificType()

            TitleChild = SItem.GetChildItem(0)
            STitleChild = TitleChild.GetSpecificType()
            STitleChild.SetTextContents(TitleText)
            # var title = Elem.GetChildItem(0)

            # title.SetTextContents(TitleText)
finally:
    SpssClient.StopClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running in external mode.  Are you sure that what you see in the Python window isn't the text being echoed from the Viewer file back as plain text?  If you call

spss.SetOutput("OFF")

it will suppress output echoing to Python.